# Cannot load type from load type 'System.Drawing.Font' from assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, syncfusion

I know there are similar questions but i couldn't find the answer so i will ask a specif question.
I have a simple .net core console application.
I'm using the Syncfusion.DocIO.Base and Syncfusion.Core assemblies to create a WordDocument from a stream like this:

```
var word = new WordDocument(rtfStream, FormatType.Rtf);
```

here i get the error message:
**Could not load type 'System.Drawing.Font' from assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.'**

Do you have any idea where can i look to reslove this problem?`

Comment: hi, try to check weather System.Drawing is in output folder of your application. Maybe you need to copy it on build. Looks like one of dependencies of Syncfusion do not coping on build.

Comment: @VladimirShmidt I see System.Drawing in Dependencies->SDK->System.Drawing. If this is not what you mean, please tell me what do you mean when you say output folder? thanks

Comment: Have you used nuget package manager to pull all required libraries. I guess you are missing above dependencies used by other dll. this dlls are added into your reference?

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar I have added the Syncfusion references to my assembly and they use the System.Drawing dll. I have the System.Drawing.dll in the SDK->Microsoft.NETCore.App. The same thing happened when i pulled the libraries from nuget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `System.Drawing.Font` is not available in .NET Core 2.0. While .NET Core has a `System.Drawing.dll` and `System.Drawing.Primitives.dll`, those do not contain this type just as many more expected by libraries making use of the full .NET Framework's drawing capabilities.

Support for these features is planned for .NET Core 2.1, see the [related GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/20325).

Answer (score 0):

You have referred base assemblies which contains “System.Drawing” reference which is not supported in ASP.NET Core application.

So, please refer the following assemblies/NuGet packages to work with Word documents using Essential DocIO in ASP.NET Core.

```
Syncfusion.Compression.Portable
Syncfusion.DocIO.Portable
Syncfusion.OfficeChart.Portable
```

1. You can find the installed assemblies and NuGet packages from below location.
   $system drive:\Users\$user.nuget\packages\Syncfusion.DocIO.Portable
   Eg : C:\Users\username.nuget\packages\Syncfusion.DocIO.Portable
2. You can find the ASP.NET Core NuGet packages in online from below link.
   http://nuget.syncfusion.com/package/aspnetcore

Please refer the below link to know more about migration changes for ASP.NET Core.
https://help.syncfusion.com/aspnet-core/release-notes/migratingtov15.3.0.26?type=all

Please refer the below UG documentation links to know more about ASP.NET Core configuration with Essential DocIO.

https://help.syncfusion.com/aspnet-core/gettingstarted/getting-started-1-1-0
https://help.syncfusion.com/aspnet-core/installation

https://help.syncfusion.com/aspnet-core/gettingstarted/getting-started-1-1-0#configure-syncfusion-file-format-components-in-aspnet-core-application

https://help.syncfusion.com/aspnet-core/docio/overview

**For further questions please contact our support team at support@syncfusion.com to get a prompt assistance on this.**