# Could not load type 'System.Drawing.FontStyle'

Tags: asp.net

I have a library of classes which work with graphic by system.drowing and web-application on .net core 2. When I try to create object object of class from this lybrary in controller it throws exception

TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Drawing.FontStyle' from assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Please, help to solve problem!

Comment: Do you have `using System.Drawing;` in your code?

Comment: Yes. There is no compilation errors, exception is throwed in runtime

Comment: Then you need to edit your post to include the source code

Comment: I think it's the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47227347/27703